# why am i getting this error. It Should check if user is permitted to access the view

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, roles

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

```
RolesCovidDbEntities db = new RolesCovidDbEntities();
        var dataItem = db.Logins.Where(x => x.Username == model.Username && x.Password == model.Password).First();        // this is where the error occurs 
        if (dataItem != null)

        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(dataItem.Username, false);
           if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
               && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
           {
               return Redirect(returnUrl);
           }
           else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you are using `First()` which will throw exception if the fetched list is empty. Consider using `FirstOrDefault()` rather in which case `dataItem` will be set to `null`.

As already commented, you don't need to separately use `Where` since `FirstOrDefault()` accepts a predicate too and thus you can pass the same predicate here like

```
var dataItem = db.Logins
     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == model.Username && x.Password == model.Password);
```

Comment: Can also remove the `Where` and put the predicate inside the call to `FirstOrDefault`